# Laravel 5.8 - Query products that belong to current category using Laravel-nestedset

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.8 with [Laravel-nestedset](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset) for my category model and I have a product model.

I am successfully creating nested categories and displaying them properly, but when I get to a category that has a product, I want to product(s) that belong to the current category to display--the code below with show products, but not in the category that they belong to.  This is pretty standard stuff I imagine, but I can't seem to figure it out.

**Category.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Spatie\Sluggable\HasSlug;
use Spatie\Sluggable\SlugOptions;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Kalnoy\Nestedset\NodeTrait;

class Category extends Model
{
    use \Spatie\Tags\HasTags;
    use HasSlug;
    use NodeTrait;

    public function getSlugOptions() : SlugOptions
    {
        return SlugOptions::create()
            ->generateSlugsFrom('name')
            ->saveSlugsTo('slug');
    }

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
}
```

**Product.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Spatie\Sluggable\HasSlug;
use Spatie\Sluggable\SlugOptions;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use \Spatie\Tags\HasTags;
    use HasSlug;

    protected $dates = [
        'published_on',
    ];

    public function getSlugOptions() : SlugOptions
    {
        return SlugOptions::create()
            ->generateSlugsFrom('title')
            ->saveSlugsTo('slug');
    }

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

**CategoryController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Category;
use App\Product;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function index()

    {
        $categories = Category::get()->toTree();;

        return view('categories.index', compact('categories'));
    }

    public function show(Category $category)
    {
        $products = Product::with('category')->whereIn('category_id', $category)->get();
        return view('categories.show', compact('category', 'products'));
    }

}
```

**show.blade.php (this is the category show template and where I want the products to show)**

```
...
@if (count($category['children']) > 0)
    @foreach($category['children']->chunk(3) as $chunk)
        <div class="row">
            @foreach($chunk as $category)
                <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-bottom: 2rem">
                    <div class="feature-box center media-box fbox-bg">
                        <div class="fbox-media">
                            <a href="/{{$category->slug}}">
                                <img class="image_fade"
                                     src="https://*****.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/{{ $category->photo }}"
                                     alt="Featured Box Image"
                                     style="opacity: 1;"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fbox-desc">
                            <h3>{{$category->name}}</h3>
                            <span><a href="{{$category->slug}}">Learn More</a></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
@if(count($products) > 0)
    @foreach($products as $product)
        {{$product->title}}
    @endforeach
@endif
...
```

Comment: In this line `Product::with('category')->whereIn('category_id', $category)->get();`, `whereIn()` takes an array as the second argument. You should just use `where()`.

Comment: When I change `whereIn` to `where` no products are displayed.

Comment: perhaps thinking about the reverse relationship might work? i.e. `$products = $category->products()`

Comment: Sorry, still no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Define the `products()` relationship in the Category model

```php
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

And you access the relationship from an instantiated category like so:

```php
@if (count($category['children']) > 0)
    @foreach($category['children']->chunk(3) as $chunk)
        <div class="row">
            @foreach($chunk as $category)
                // ...
                @foreach($category->products as $product)
                @endforeach
                // ...
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```